# Use CodeIgniter Active Record to convert MySQL query

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Can anybody convert the normal mysql query into codeigniter update strcuture.

```
UPDATE game_rounds 
SET from_score = CASE WHEN from_id = 2 THEN 65 ELSE from_score END,
    to_score = CASE WHEN to_id = 2 THEN 65 ELSE to_score END 
WHERE round_id=5
```

I tried update_batch but not able to find correct solution.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->db
    ->set('from_score', 'CASE WHEN from_id = 2 THEN 65 ELSE from_score END', FALSE)
    ->set('to_score', 'CASE WHEN to_id = 2 THEN 65 ELSE to_score END', FALSE)
    ->where('round_id', 5)
    ->update('game_rounds');
```

$this->db->set() enables you to set values for inserts or updates.
It can be used instead of passing a data array directly to the insert or update functions.

The optional **third parameter** ($escape), that will prevent data from being escaped if set to FALSE.

[CI Active Record Class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to do this

```
$data['from_score'] =   'CASE WHEN from_id = 2 THEN 65 ELSE from_score END';
$data['to_score']   =   'CASE WHEN to_id = 2 THEN 65 ELSE to_score END ';

$this->db->where('round_id',5);
$this->db->update('game_rounds',$data);
```

After that run `echo $this->db->last_query()` to see if it is generating correct query string.